# Now that Redis Cluster comes with sharding, replication and automatic failover, do i still need to use Sentinel for failover handling?

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, redis-cluster

Now that Redis Cluster comes with sharding, replication and automatic failover, do i still need to use Sentinel for failover handling ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Sentinel is for managing the availability and providing service discovery when using Redis in single instance mode (single-master/one-or-more-slaves). When using Redis in cluster mode, Sentinel isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks. I was actully quite confused as to what architecture I should go with for my cloud deployment.

Comment: Why isn't sentinel needed when sharding?

Comment: @DonRhummy because Redis Cluster has its own failover and discovery mechanisms